Problem with token as link in nextjs 14 catch all routes
I tried to render a page in catch all routes where the link shows $2b$10$st1pBEJx.g3aWVVrkYl1GOXr2u1OZNCsC1okCWgOlSmiGNEN4YzY6 but when I log out the params it shows as
%242b%2410%24st1pBEJx.g3aWVVrkYl1GOXr2u1OZNCsC1okCWgOlSmiGNEN4YzY6 which are two different tokens and I don't know why please help.
Please pay attention to the first 4 or 5 preceding digits of the token.
The token should render the same but it renders differently.

When you're using symbols in a URI, you have to keep in mind that they might get converted if they are reserved. 
Example: When doing a Google search, if you;ve noticed, there is a query: https://google.com/search?q=sandwhich

The ? symbol is reserved for query params in the URL.
Also, anytime there is a space between words, they handle the spaces by replacing it with the + symbol.

The reason why it's being changed to a $ might have something to do with the way the browser handles certain symbols. I would redirect you to this post which asks a very similar question: What does dollar sign $ do in url?

I hope this helped.
